# Merging Mutliple Rows from Data Extension into Email - Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I have a data extension named "MemberList" and I am attempting to create an email to apply members who are missing items to become full members.  Some are missing one item, some four to five items.  I need to have all the missing items go into a list in an email and am struggling with getting the items grouped by "memberId" and using a for loop, putting the items into one email.  Here is the code I am working with:

```
%%[

/* setting the variables and looking up columns and data within the Data Extension*/

Var @firstName, @lastName, @email, @location, @itemCode,@itemDescription,@memberId,@rows,@row,@rowCount

Set @firstName = FirstName
Set @lastName = LastName
Set @email = EmailAddress
Set @location = Location
Set @itemCode = ItemCode
Set @itemDescription = ItemDescription
Set @memberId = MemberID

Set @rows = Lookup("MemberList", "MemberID", @memberId)
Set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

/*for loop*/

for @i = 1 to rowCount(@rows) do

  Set @row= ROW(@rows, @i)

]%%
<tr>
    <td>%%=Field(@row, @location)=%%</td>
    <td>%%=Field(@row, @itemCode)=%%</td>
</tr>

%%[
next @i
]%%
```

Error I am receiving when doing a send preview in Marketing Cloud is:

> Invalid column name (parameter 2) passed to Field function. No column
>   of the specified name was found. Invalid Field Name: WA Function:
>   Field(@row, Location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. The error indicates that you don't have a field named 'Location' in the context of the Sendable Data Extension that you are using to send the email. I assume you are using a different DE to send from (i.e. you are not using 'MemberList' DE).

Also, you should be using `LookupRows()` instead of `Lookup()`. The following code will work.

```javascript
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 400px;
}

td, th {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Item Code</th>
  </tr>

%%[

var @firstName, @lastName, @email,
var @itemDescription, @memberId, @rows, @row, @rowCount

Set @memberId = AttributeValue('MemberID')
Set @rows = LookupRows("MemberList", "MemberID", @memberId)
Set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

var @i
for @i = 1 to @rowcount do
set @row = Row(@rows,@i) 

]%%

   <tr>
      <td>%%=Field(@row, "Location")=%%</td>                                                                                          
      <td>%%=Field(@row, "ItemCode")=%%</td>
   </tr>

%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

 <tr><td colspan="2" >No records found.</td></tr>

%%[ endif ]%% 

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: MembersList is the same data extension that I am referencing and sending from.  That can't be done?

Comment: Yes it can be done and my code should work for that scenario too. I was just referring to the error message that you we're seeing, which is typically returned when the field does not exist.

Comment: Be aware that if you have duplicate MemberID values in your Sendable DE (which it appears you do), then you will want to de-duplicate by email address at time of sending, otherwise the members will receive multiple emails (one for each row where they appear). The preferred solution would be to create a separate DE containing a single `MemberID` field and write a query to populate that DE from your MemberList DE, something like: `SELECT DISTINCT [MemberID] FROM [MemberList]` — then use this new DE as your Sendable DE.